# ASP.NET Core 5 - CreatedAtAction not returning any data when returning complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller method that should be returning a complex object:

```
public class ComplexObject {
  public User User {get; set;}
  public Job Job {get; set;}
}

public class User {
  public string UserId {get; set;}
}
public class Job {
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

So, in my controller method, I return the data as follows:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetJob), new { id = jobId }, new ComplexObject { User = new User{ UserId = "hello" }, Job = new Job{ Id = jobId } });
```

Here, the caller (some client app, using HttpClient) gets an empty json object. If I send back just a job, or just a user

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetJob), new { id = jobId }, new User { UserId = "hello" });
```

the returned body contains the actual object I plugged in.

Any idea what I can do to get the full `ComplexObject` to be returned?

Tried the same with the `Created` method and an `ActionLink` but same story.

The full controller method looks like this (stripped to the bare minimum)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] AddUserParameters obj)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return GenerateBadRequest();
    int jobId = 1;
    var result = new ComplexObject { User = new User { UserId = "hello" }, Job = new Job{ Id = jobId } }
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetJob), new { id = jobId }, result);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Job/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetJob(int id, bool includeDependentElements = false)
{
    var job = new Job { Id = id };
    return Ok(job);
}
```

the other side is calling the method as follows

```
public async Task<ComplexObject>> AddUserWithReload(AddUserParameters obj)
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{apiPath}/{usersPath}", obj).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultObj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ComplexObject>().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        string jobId = response.Headers.Location.Segments.LastOrDefault();
        if (int.TryParse(jobId, out int intJobId))
            ; // do something with it
        return resultObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CorentinPane [The `CreatedAtAction` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L2069) is provided by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Do you still get an empty json, if you serialize to json yourself?

Comment: Can you post  the action pls?

Comment: I don't understand something. 
How come both caller and callee call return CreatedAtAction (and with the callee returns just the user) ?
Shouldn't the caller (whose a client) issue a request to the callee (server) with a HttpClient?
Can you show the server controller and how you call it from the client?

Comment: @YomB: I mistyped.. I wrote callee (which would be the server side.. so the code I'm showing), when I meant caller (some remote application, contacting my web api application). I corrected the description when I added the full controller method

Comment: @StephanSteiner can you also show the HttpClient call?

Comment: At least your code worked for me when I call the api in the tool.  So I'm afraid your client should be post here.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTQt.png

Comment: @YomB I posted how I'm calling this code. When `ComplexObject` was empty from the httpClient, I tried `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead, only to get this: `{}` so.. empty object, no content. If I return a `User` object, and read the `response.Content` as `User`, I get the filled out user.

Comment: @StephanSteiner I you use await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync, but httpClient exposes PostAsync (as Task). Is it your own custom extension method?
Also, you use apiPath + userPath, while the Add method on the controller expects only the controller route, so maybe you hit a different method/controller?

Comment: @YomB: `PostAsJsonAsync` extension from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget (or `System.Net.Http` - can't be sure because my work box is on the frizz just now). Nothing custom going on here. And yes, I know this is hitting my controller, I was debugging both ends of the problem.. I have an interceptor on the server side, and I can see that it sends out just `{}`, so it's most definitely not a client side problem.

Comment: I see.. it's very weird indeed, should work if you say it is hitting the controller..
Two things I've noticed in the client function: 
- response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{apiPath}/{usersPath}", obj).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);

'response' is not prefixed with var - is it a typo? Or captured from outside the function?

-it's signature says Task<RestApiOperationResult<ComplexObject>> rather than Task<ComplexObject> as it returns just the ComplexObject?

Comment: I didn't really bother to make the client side part functional.. I ripped out a part of my perfectly working code. All error handling etc. is removed. But it works just fine where I use it. And since the server doesn't send out the data, no point looking at the client side of things ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally had some time to look at it again. The suggestions to try and look what happens if I serialize the response myself was helpful.. got an empty json object, too. The real `ComplexObject` had two properties, too, but they were `internal`, and serialization doesn't pick these up. Made them public and all is well.